# TypeScript: unresolved variable 'MongoClient'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, webstorm

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm converting a js file into ts for the first time. I'm using WebStorm.

Although the code works, I get this warning:

> unresolved variable 'MongoClient'

And I can't go to its definition either.

Here is the code:

```
var MongoClient: any = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

What can I do in order to make TypeScript recognize it? Also I'd like to specify a specific type for "MongoClient" rather than "any".

I've included node.d.ts in my project to solve the same warning for the "require" function BTW.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: It's a bug. Stop using shitty webstorm (j/k, do whatever you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding mongodb.d.ts to my project.
I downloaded it from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts

Generally, for each third party js module there might be a corresponding vendorName.d.ts file in DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: No need to download the type definitions manually. There is a tool for that: https://github.com/typings/typings

Answer (score 0):

In general, search for a module on [TypeSearch](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) and install the package simply as follows:

```
npm install --save @types/mongodb
```